# how to match values of a line by values of another line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a css file with the following structure:

```
#reg-1 {
top: 7.13%;
left: 7.36%;
height: 16.06%;
width: 85.14%;
}
#reg-1-magTarget {
top: 64.13%;
left: 36.36%;
height: 12.06%;
width: 99.14%;
}
#reg-2 {
top: 26.25%;
left: 21.49%;
height: 26.17%;
width: 55.19%;
}
#reg-2-magTarget {
top: 33.09%;
left: 17.27%;
height: 26.41%;
width: 45.04%;
}
```

And wanted to find a way to match the values of "#reg-1 {" by replacing the ones of "#reg-1-magTarget {" in notepad++ with regular expressions

to something like this:

```
#reg-1 {
top: 7.13%;
left: 7.36%;
height: 16.06%;
width: 85.14%;
}
#reg-1-magTarget {
top: 7.13%;
left: 7.36%;
height: 16.06%;
width: 85.14%;
}
#reg-2 {
top: 26.25%;
left: 21.49%;
height: 26.17%;
width: 55.19%;
}
#reg-2-magTarget {
top: 26.25%;
left: 21.49%;
height: 26.17%;
width: 55.19%;
}
```

I really don't know much about this but I was interested and I was trying combinations

I began to structure little by little the regex necessary to match it
try first

`#reg-(\d) {`
then I corrected it with this
`#reg-(\d{1,2}) {`

then i completed it

`#reg-(\d{1,2}) {(\r\n)top:\s\d{1,2}(\r\n)left:\s\d{1,2}`

then change to

`#reg-(\d{1,9})-magTarget(\s){(\r\n)top:(\s)(\d{1,9})(\r\n)left:(\ s)(\d{1,9})`

then search, I think it could work something like:
`^(.+?)\h+:\h+"`
by
`$0$1`
what makes this
Afghanistan: ''
be
Afghanistan : 'Afghanistan'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9cq0TL/1)):

```
(#reg-\d+)(.*?})\s+\1-magTarget.*?}
```

And for replacement

```
\1 \2\n\1-magTarget \2
```

Note: check `Regular expression` and `. matches newline`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Find what:**

```
(#reg-\d+)([^}]*})\R\K\1-magTarget[^}]*}
```

The pattern matches:

- `(#reg-\d+)` Capture *group 1*, match `#reg-` and 1+ digits
- `([^}]*})` Capture *group 2*, Match 0+ times any char except `}` and then match `}`
- `\R\K` Match a newline and then forget what is matched so far
- `\1-magTarget` A backreference to the same what is matched in group 1, followed by matching `-magTarget`
- `[^}]*}` Match 0+ times any char except `}` and then match `}`

**Replace with:**

```
\1-magTarget \2
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ibpHw6/1).

[image]

---

But perhaps you can prevent the duplication of the css by writing the result as:

```
#reg-1, #reg-1-magTarget {
top: 7.13%;
left: 7.36%;
height: 16.06%;
width: 85.14%;
}
#reg-2, #reg-2-magTarget {
top: 26.25%;
left: 21.49%;
height: 26.17%;
width: 55.19%;
}
```

**Find what:**

```
(#reg-\d+)([^}]*})\R\1-magTarget[^}]*}
```

**Replace with:**

```
\1, \1-magTarget\2
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQWJLG/1).

[image]